# Create a new data frame based on conditions from columns of a given dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I have following data frame,

df.head()

```
UID     Timestamp       Weekday  Business_hour
AAD 2017-07-11 09:31:44 TRUE    TRUE
AAD 2017-07-11 23:24:43 TRUE    FALSE
AAD 2017-07-12 13:24:43 TRUE    TRUE
SAP 2017-07-23 14:24:34 FALSE   FALSE
SAP 2017-07-24 16:58:49 TRUE    TRUE
YAS 2017-07-31 21:10:35 TRUE    FALSE
```

based on the following conditions,

Active: Whether the same UID has larger events.That is, when same UID appeared more 2+ times in the same day.

Multiple_days: Whether the same UID is active for multiple days (2+ days).

Busi_weekday: Whether the same UID tends to occur during weekday business hours.

The aimed output should look like,

```
UID Active  Multiple_days   Busi_weekday
AAD TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
SAP FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
YAS FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt at this already? My suggestion would be to create 2 new columns, "Date" [exc time, mapped from Timestamp] and "Busi_weekday" [Boolean, determined from Timestamp]. Then perform a pandas.groupby.count. Have a go and include your code, you are then more likely to get good responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate them one by one like this:

```
data.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(data.Timestamp)
data['date' ] = [x.date() for x in data.Timestamp]

target_df = pd.DataFrame()
target_df['UID'] = data.UID.unique()


a = data.groupby(['UID', 'date']).size()
a = a[a>1]
target_df['Active'] = [True if x in pd.DataFrame(a).reset_index().UID.values else False for x in target_df.UID.values]

a = data.groupby('UID')['Timestamp'].nunique()
a = a[a>1]
target_df['Multiple_days'] = [True if x in pd.DataFrame(a).reset_index().UID.values else False for x in target_df.UID.values]

a = data[(data.Weekday==True)&(data.Business_hour==True)].UID.unique()
target_df['Busi_weekday'] = [True if x in a else False for x in target_df.UID.values]

target_df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I got it, the primary data frame is really big and the above script is running since an hour now

Comment: don't know, try finding the exact line(s) that takes so much time, you can also try putting  "pd.DataFrame(a).reset_index().UID.values" in a variable and iterate on that.

Comment: Yes trying that